# Detect IFRAME blocking?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm working on a site that will display HTML content from other links within an IFRAME.  I know that a lot of sites have JavaScript code that will detect the content is being displayed in an IFRAME and prevent it from rendering.  I'd like to be able to detect the presence of this IFRAME blocking code, and redirect the user to the original page (without the IFRAME) if it would normally be block.

Try as I might, though, I haven't found anything reasonable that works.  Have any of you implemented something like this?  Any pointers?

**UPDATE:**  For those of you who want to see what I'm talking about, [here is a link](http://www.gurufoo.com/articles/view.xhtml?aid=purpose-of-threadlocal-in-java-and-when-to-use-thr-20264989) that shows the behavior.  If you look at it in Firebug, you'll see that the HTML content from the IFRAME is empty.

Comment: Don't think there is any way other than making a call beforehand and checking the headers.

Comment: Can you show an example of a site that prevents the frame from rendering? What does it do? Does it show different content or does it redirect the user?

Comment: The site you linked to (java.dzone)  does not use javascript to block the iframe. It uses an HTTP header called `X-Frame-Options` and it is set to 'SAMEORIGIN'. This prevents it from displaying in a browser. You could either get the headers of the website server side or client side and check for the existence of this particular http header

Comment: @soniiic I took a look, and you are definitely correct.  Feel free to add this as an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: I'm having a similar issue. If your site is https, the browser will block the iframe if it is not https, or if it contains any resource served by http. I'm trying to figure out how to detect these [browser-level blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59336591/) using client-side javascript.